# PHP Check image size and show the error

Tags: php

I was following this tutorial for uploading an image.I could n't figure out,how is this checking file file,if the file size exceed,it should an error.

Here is the link http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/php/article.php/3877766/Web-Developer-How-To-Upload-Images-Using-PHP.htm

Can some one explain,how is this code checking the file size and validating it.

Comment: Please include the code directly in your question.

Comment: @Vulcan:Since it has lot many lines of code,i shared the link.

Answer (score 3):

The link which you provide, it has been mentioned the `$max_file_size = 30000;`. So that if you exceed the max size it will be error on uploading. If you want to ignored it then make comment on `//$max_file_size = 30000;`. Then it will worked.

Comment: :Can you tell me,how is the code validating image size ? It is not working,if i use that code so i need to under stand the logic to fix it.

Comment: :Is that 3000 is equal to 3 MB.

Comment: No here 3000 measured in bytes that means its value in KB is 2.92KB. So if you upload more than 2.92 KB file it will show error.

Comment: :If i've to give the value for 3 MB,what would be the value ?

Comment: You have entered 3145728 value. Just a simple calculation to find the size in MB. 1MB = 1024KB and 1KB = 1024 Bytes and 1Bytes = 8 bit

Answer (score 0):

In upload.form.php you specify:

```
$max_file_size = 30000; // size in bytes
```

this will automatically fills the input form directive:

```
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="<?php echo $max_file_size ?>">
```

The server side check is in upload.processor.php

```
($_FILES[$fieldname]['error'] == 0) 
    or error($errors[$_FILES[$fieldname]['error']], $uploadForm);
```

If the selected file's size exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive in the HTML form, then $_FILES[$fieldname]['error'] returns error code 2.
Any kind of error code returned by S_FILES is catched by this check, which will call the function 'error'.

Info about $_FILES error messages can be found at:
[php files: error messages explained](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)